# Using template file to generate unique files locally with p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a template JS file where I need to change 1 variable and then save a copy of that js file. I cannot use node because it does not support p5. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this locally.

```js
let result;
function preload() {
  result = loadStrings('template.js')
}
function setup() {
  if (result[0] != null) {
    result[0] = "let number = "+"\"" + 1 + "\"";
    let writer = createWriter('modifiedTemplate.js');
    writer.write(result)
    writer.close()  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to load a file, edit it and save it as a new file. In that case, what you have is pretty much there.

The only potential issues I can see are the following -
Let's say you have a templates file that looks like:

```
let number = 10;
let count = 4;
```

And you want to change `let number = 10` to `let number = 1`. First of all, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do that:

```
result[0] = `let number = 1;`;
```

Then what you have should save the file, however it wouldn't be in the format you might expect - the output of the file would be:

```
let number = 1;,let count = 4;
```

That's the nature of the [javascript toString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) method. I'd recommend joining the array and separating each line by a new line:

```
writer.write(result.join('\n'));
```

Which should output like the following:

```
let number = 1;
let count = 4;
```

If you get stuck I've implemented this in a [p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/5R0WNLybS) which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the improvements but the problem with my current code is that the file is being saved client side. I would like to copy these files into the same directory that I have the js script and html in